# Download NextCloud file using WebDav API and Python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, webdav, nextcloud

I have a markdown file on a NextCloud 15 server, in `MyDirectory/`.

So far I've been able to list `MyDirectory/` content, despite the fact that documentation is not very consistent with what is actually working.

For example, I'm using `https://cloud.example.com/remote.php/webdav/folder` instead of `https://cloud.example.com/remote.php/dav/files/username/folder` as said in the doc. My (working) code:

```py
import requests
import xmltodict

webdav_options = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <d:propfind xmlns:d="DAV:">
                <d:prop xmlns:oc="http://owncloud.org/ns">
                    <d:getlastmodified/>
                    <d:getcontenttype/>
                    <oc:fileid/>
                </d:prop>
            </d:propfind>"""

r = requests.request('PROPFIND', 'https://my-domain.com/nextcloud/remote.php/webdav/MyDirectory',
                     auth=('username', 'password'),
                     data=webdav_options
                     )

xml_dict = xmltodict.parse(r.text, dict_constructor=dict)

for response in xml_dict['d:multistatus']['d:response']:
    filename = unquote(response['d:href']).replace(
        '/nextcloud/remote.php/webdav/', '')
    print(filename) # Working great
```

Now I would like to download the files. Following the documentation [found here](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/15/developer_manual/client_apis/WebDAV/basic.html#downloading-files) is not working... Trying this only downloads an html page:

```py
url = f'https://my-domain.com/nextcloud/remote.php/webdav/MyDirectory/{filename}'
my_file = requests.get(url, auth=(usernanme, password))
print(my_file.content) # html content
```

Any idea how to proceed ?

Comment: you ever got this to work?

Comment: This is very late, but check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60936116/ . I use ``https://mynextcloudinstanceurl/remote.php/dav/files/my_user_name/mydirectory/myfile.pdf`` . Then you have to write the returned content to a file like: ```if response.status_code == 200:
        with open("path/to/dir/file.pdf", 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)```